# vmware iscsi adapter not seeing LUNS

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

Have three virtually identical boxes.  However one box after enabling the storage adapter and adding dynamic targets (where it actually sees the targets) after a rescan I still don't see the available LUNS.  Any ideas ?

[image]

[image]

Edit Update:

I dumped the logs, there are some errors about an authentication error to the iscsi target (ProdLun-1), which is strange becuase I don't have CHAP enabled.

```
-->          value = "iqn.2000-01.com.synology:synorack.prodlun",
2013-10-16T02:00:49.459Z [40ACDB90 info 'Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr'] Event 148 : Login to iSCSI   target iqn.2000-01.com.synology:synorack.prodlun on vmhba37 failed. Target returned login   error of: 0206.
2013-10-16T02:00:53.700Z [FFD40B90 info 'Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr'] Event 149 : Login to iSCSI   target iqn.2000-01.com.synology:synorack.prodlun on vmhba37 failed. The iSCSI initiator could    not establish a network connection to the target.
-->          value = "iqn.2000-01.com.synology:diskstatbackupm.backup",
2013-10-16T02:00:53.703Z [40C80B90 info 'Vimsvc.ha-eventmgr'] Event 151 : Login to iSCSI   target iqn.2000-01.com.synology:diskstatbackupm.backup on vmhba37 failed. The iSCSI initiator    could not establish a network connection to the target.
```

[Full Log](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4eRlmWdOdXudVpnM1JZazd1Rzg/edit?usp=sharing)

[iScsi Error KB:](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2001449)

Comment: Nothing in logs on ESXi server?

Comment: Have you been able to verify connectivity via vmkping to the iSCSI targets? Have you ensured the LUN's have been published to the host?

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Yeah just checked that appears to be an authentication error (which also doesn't make a ton of sense).

Comment: @Rex yes I can ping the targets.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna and have you ensured it the LUN is mapped so that is available to the host?

Comment: @Rex I'm assuming yes it is on the same private network as the 2 others hosts and there is no authentication setup on the target.  So yes i'm assuming it should be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebooting the ESXi server? In my experience the iSCSI software stack sometimes locks up connections (a little like zombie processes) if your connection has suffered from some of these highlights:

1. Cable disconnect while LUN was mounted
2. iSCSI target temporary disconnected / taken inactive for NAS reboots / reconfiguration
3. Another host performing - sort of a man in middle - hijack of the LUN.

We must think of an iSCSI endpoint 'drive' as if it was a physical disk or more precise, like an amount of bytes allocated through the SCSI driver stack. Trying to parallel connect a cable to a diskdrive is not supported in the physical term - and the SCSI driver cannot handle this.

I've found myself waiting endlessly for timeouts when forgetting to detach mounted LUNs - realizing it simply was not about to happen without a complete reboot of the server.

Make sure you do NOT have any iSCSI Connectors running from another server (locking the LUN on my NAS down with IP restriction works for me). Then reboot the ESXi server and while its doing the reboot - stop/start the iSCSI service which is hosting your physical disks just in case (in my setup, this would be the NAS)

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a Synology NAS. You need to go to the storage manager, then select ISCSI target. Edit the setting and allow for multiple sessions from one or more ISCSI initiators.